# How to keep the filterBy value of rich:datatable in session scope?

Tags: java, events, richfaces

Is it possible to keep the filterBy value of a `rich:datatable rich:column filterBy="..."` in SESSION scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use el expression pointing to property of bean that is put in session scope.

```
<rich:datatable ...>
 <rich:column filterValue="#{yourSessionBean.filterByProperty}" ... >
...
```

I'm assuming you want to store `filterValue` not `filterBy`.

Comment: It's not that easy... filterBy points to a field of the entity used to fill the datatable. So I can't simply use a session bean. If the datatable loops with value="#{myEntities} var="e" than I use something like filterBy="#{e.field}".

Comment: @Daniel So you need store `filterValue` attribute value not `filterBy`. Am I right?

Comment: Ah... this might be a solution... I'll test it. Thanks so far.